# Batch file to check program installation

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to determine if some program has been installed and, if it has, open it. If the program has not been installed, an alternate program should open.

For example, if Notepad++ has been installed, the script should open that; if not, Notepad should be opened instead.

Any advice at all would be appreciated, as I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Depends on how much effort you want to take to do it right... from your tags i assume you want to open notepad++ and fall back to notepad if it is not installed. If you know where the preferred target is installed you could simply check if the executable is present.

Comment: @ Dlanod Kcud How to do it ? I don't have any basic knowledge  in batch file creation.

Comment: `if exist` will check for the existence of a program or file. Look at the output of `if /?` for how to use an if statement.

Comment: Can anyone post a proper answer.I am very noob in batch file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have a specific question about a part of your code that is not working, edit your question to include the code and we will tell you why it is not working.

Comment: @SomethingDark I know it not but i don't know how to write a script for a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
cls & color 0B
Mode con cols=90 lines=5
set Location=%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++
set FileName=Notepad++.exe
echo( & cls
echo(  & echo  Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "%Location%"
TimeOut /T 3 /NoBreak>Nul
cls
IF EXIST "%Location%\%FileName%" ( color 0A && echo The "%FileName%" is installed && pause && Start "" "%Location%\%FileName%" 
) ELSE (
    Color 0C & echo The "%FileName%" is not installed & pause & Start "" "Notepad.exe"
)
```

Comment: So should i change `Notepad++.exe` with my application?I have one more question is this will work both on 64&32 bit?

Comment: where to set the location for `Notepad.exe`,in my case it is located in the same folder where `.bat` file is located.